# Animating a DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a div's width after the page loads, but I cannot get it to work.

Basically the div is set to display:none and I want to animate it's width after the page is ready.

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.graph').animate({width:"40%"},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
});
});
</script>

.graph {width: 400px;
height: 250px;
position: absolute;
background-image: url(../images/roll.png);
display: none;
}
```

I can never get jquery to work, sigh.

Comment: Could you post the code onto jsFiddle?

Comment: You should generally use one unit of measurement, it will help with issues in the future and code readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery doesn't know to make your element visible all on its own. You're telling it to animate the width of an element that you've explicitly told your browser to hide, using CSS. As such, you need to first show the element, and then animate it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#foo")
        .show()
        .animate(
            { width: "40%" }, 
            { duration: 600, easing: 'easeOutBounce' }
        );    
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjCnX/1/

Answer (score 0):

That is cause of `display: none;` Also your code is not valid.

Please check this jsFiddle example, it will solve the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/af2yj/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".graph").show();
    $('.graph').animate({width:"40%"},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
});
​
```

In your example you had unused }); and you didn't close the animate() function with semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".graph").show();
```

you have to .show(); it first... That because display: none; is hiding it, and you are not showing it...